# Dynamic function to get name from url separated with dash (-)

Tags: javascript

I have to get a URL using javascript that contains the following string is like

```
karachi-hotels
abu-dubai-hotels
phi-phi-island-hotels
phi-phi-hotels
kaula-lampur-hotels
```

using javascript I want to get the city name like

```
karachi
abu-dubai
phi-phi-island
and etc
```

Comment: "karachi-hotels abu-dubai-hotels phi-phi-island-hotels phi-phi-hotels kaula-lampur-hotels".match(/[\w\-]*?(?=-hotels)/g).filter(v=>v)

Comment: Removed references to [tag:jquery] as this is a vanilla-javascript operation and nothing to do with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

To remove "*-hotels*", you can use native `replaceAll()` and `split()` methods.

```js
var hotels = "karachi-hotels abu-dubai-hotels phi-phi-island-hotels phi-phi-hotels kaula-lampur-hotels";

var cities = hotels
  .replaceAll("-hotels", "") // It removes all "-hotels"
  .split(" "); // It returns an array of all locations.

console.log(cities) // [ 'karachi', 'abu-dubai', 'phi-phi-island', 'phi-phi', 'kaula-lampur' ]
```